# What is the pull request equivalent for tfs?

Tags: tfs

What is the pull request equivalent in TFS?

I'm asking specifically about cross team collaboration, where there is a team responsible for the product but other teams can work on their own copy and submit "pull requests".

So the core team still owns the product, but other teams can still contribute to it.

Comment: Are you maybe talking about branches? Because otherwise, there's nothing preventing a member of another team from checking in code.

Comment: You can also set up a team project that uses Git for source control, if you're using TFS2013.

Comment: @JohnSaunders see Dylan's answer, yes, you can do, but it is not exactly the same. Notice how it ends up with an email asking to merge their changes (which will need to include, revisions, locations, etc.). Pull requests provide a clear process on this area. Also if the flow is recognized by the product, it helps selling the idea on companies used to treat cross team collaboration as closed source :)

Answer (score 4):

There is not really an equivalent (yet).

An external team could branch off the main branch, make their changes, then send an email asking the owning team to merge in the external team's branch into the main branch.